# /requests endpoint response doesn't match documentation

Tags: uber-api

I'm looking at the response for a request to /v1/requests/{request_id} but it doesn't match what is described in the documentation. In particular, I was hoping to get start lat/lng and end/lat among other information, but it seems like none of that is being returned. Is this a bug?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is being returned? Did you consider the status of your trip? Based on the status, the response content will vary.

Answer (score 0):

Without further details, my assumption is that you are looking at a trip that is not ongoing. As you can find [in the documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests-details), the pickup and destination fields are populated **only when a trip is active**.

If that is not helpful, please provide the HTTP request details (e.g. cURL), HTTP response payload and some details about the trips status to help us help you solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response - so does the API not expose information like start lat/lng to developers who want to look at past rides?

Comment: Correct. The API only exposes start location for historical rides. For trips that are currently in-progress we provide all of the details.